# Почему нельзя обратиться из внешнего диалогового окна в методу компонента?

Tags: javascript, angular2, typescript

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться в ситуации. Я рассмотрю 2 случая, а потом скажу расскажу как они не могу выполнить одно и то же ействие.

Случай 1:

Есть компонент:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Inject } from '@angular/core';

import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material';

import { MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material';

import { PositionComponent } from './modals/position/position.component';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private http: Http, 
              private matDialog: MatDialog) 
  { };

  public test() {
    console.log('test');
    alert('test');
  };

  public test2() {
    console.log('test2');
    alert('test2');
  };  

  private addParticipant() {
    this.matDialog.open(DialogOverviewExampleDialog, {
      width: '400px',
      data: { title: 'Создание нового участника.', id: 666  }
    });  
  };
}

В ЭТОМ ЖЕ файле я добавил компонент для material диалогового окна(шаблон dialog-overview-example-dialog.html тоже создал):
@Component({
  selector: 'dialog-overview-example-dialog',
  templateUrl: 'dialog-overview-example-dialog.html',
  providers: [AppComponent],
})
export class DialogOverviewExampleDialog {

  private id_: string = '';

  constructor(
    private appComponent: AppComponent,
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<DialogOverviewExampleDialog>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) private data: any) { 
    this.id_ = data.id;

    setTimeout(function() {
      appComponent.test();
    }, 1000);
  }

}
```

В результате когда в AppComponent наступает некоторое событие(детали я опустил), то срабатывает вызов диалогового окна через addParticipant(). Это коно открывается. Затем через 1 секунду компонент диалогового окна вызывает метод test() компонента AppComponent. Это всё работает.

Случай 2:

Я создал отдельный компонент диалогового окна(то есть в отдельном файле). Вот его код:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Inject } from '@angular/core';

import { MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material';

import { ParticipantsService } from '../../services/participants.service';
import { AppComponent } from '../../app.component';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-position',
  templateUrl: './position.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./position.component.scss'],
  providers: [AppComponent]
})
export class PositionComponent implements OnInit {

    private position: string = '';
    private id: string = '';

  constructor(private matDialogRef: MatDialogRef<PositionComponent>,
              private appComponent: AppComponent,
                        private participantsService: ParticipantsService,
                        @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any) 
  { 
    this.position = data.position;
    this.id = data.id;
  }

  private submit2(): void {
    this.appComponent.test2();
  };

}
```

Как видите, я подобным же образом импортировал AppComponent и прописал его в providers. И так же в конструкторе создал экземпляр.

Далее когда в шаблоне пользователь нажимает на кнопку:

```
<button class="btn btn-common" mat-button (click)="submit2()">
  вызвать
</button>
```

, срабатывает вызов submit2(). НО этот метод не может вызвать метод компонента AppComponent.

Консоль браузера показывает следующюю ошибку:

```
Uncaught Error: Encountered undefined provider! Usually this means you have a circular dependencies (might be caused by using 'barrel' index.ts files.
    at syntaxError (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:47518:34)
    at http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:61654:40
    at Array.forEach (native)
```

Консоль линукса не выводит никакой ошибки.

Comment: @Kain
В этом случае консоль линукса выдаёт такое сообщение об ошибке: "Cannot find name 'PositionComponent'.".
А консоль браузера "Uncaught Error: Encountered undefined provider! Usually this means you have a circular dependencies (might be caused by using 'barrel' index.ts files.".

Comment: Очень плохо инжектить компонет в компонент. Постарайтесь переписать с изпользованием сервисов или, если компонент вложен в другой, импользуйте события компонента.

Answer (score 0):

AppComponent импортируется PositionComponent, в котором импортируется AppComponent, в котором импортируется PositionComponent, в котором...Это и есть circular dependencies, о котором говорится в ошибке.

Удаление `import { PositionComponent } from './modals/position/position.component';` должно помочь

Comment: Не помогло. "Cannot find name 'PositionComponent'".
Это и ожидаемо. Потому что как будет осуществляться вызов: this.matDialog.open(PositionComponent, {

Comment: А как оно будет работать с перекрестными связями? PositionComponent находится внутри AppComponent? Почему не воспользуетесь @Output?